# MySql Database Password

Tags: mysql

I  know that to connect to a database you need 4 things: Database Name, Username, Password, Host.

And since i know very little about how MySql databases work, I'm a little confused by this little thing: Is the Password for the Database or for the Username?

Comment: Hint: databases are often used by different people.

Comment: Well, the password is set for authentication and is thus linked to the user. Actually besides Access that lets you "lock" a database through a single password without any real authentication, AFAIK all other DBMS associate username and password...

Comment: password for the username.

Comment: Why the down-votes? is just a simple question, if some of you know the answer, doesn't give you the right to down-vote a question because to you it sounds silly or something.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario thanks, i just started with MySQL for a few day, so i know very little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always for the user(-name). Databases doesn't have passwords. Users have permissions for databases or not. And the password is linked to the specific user.

Answer (score 0):

It is for the username. There is no way to you access the database without an user. You can have a blank password for an user but not the other way around.